# Error when trying to create a WinRT component dll

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I had a solution where I was building a WinRT compoent dll. I updated the Windows 8 version to Consumer Preview(from Developer Preview) and updated the Visual Studio Ultimate Beta version. Now the solution cannot load the WinRT component dll project. Also, trying to create a a new WinRT component dll gives the following error:

http://picpaste.com/Screen_Shot_2012-03-13_at_11.25.06_AM-X6Pc0MLI.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a new empty project file and manually copy the source files over. The project files are formatted and organized differently. There is no conversion routine that is officially supported.

Comment: I was trying that when I got the error in the picture above. I was trying an empty WinRT component dll project but creating a new  WinRT component dll gave the error in the picture above.

Comment: Are you running in Windows 8 Consumer Preview?

Comment: I am running the Consumer preview. I wiped out everything including my personal data and it started to work. Not sure if the fix was released or the cleaning fixed it.

Comment: Aah, the wonders of beta software. Glad it is working. For my own information, were you running an upgrade from DP, or a fresh install?

Comment: I ran an upgrade from DP initially with the "keep personal files" option. Later I ran the upgrade with a "keep nothing" option. Installed the Visual Studio 2011 BEta on top of it and it worked good. Thanks.